# Installing SXA 1.7 : One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event

Tags: sxa, installation, packages

while trying to install SXA 1.7, i have run across the following error:
One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

I uploaded the package, then proceeded with the installation wizard, only to get that error.
I've tried to re-install multiple times and i always get the same error. I tried doing an iisreset as some other websites suggested that but it didn't help.

Here is a part of the errors log:

ManagedPoolThread #10 17:04:19 ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
Exception[1]: System.NullReferenceException 
Message[1]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Source[1]: Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt 
   at Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Definitions.ItemEventHandler.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.b__0(Guid templateId)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Definitions.ItemEventHandler.DeployItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)

ManagedPoolThread #10 17:04:19 ERROR Failed to save the item. Item ID: {FA86AD54-9CEC-4509-9EFD-DD6DBC608A5B}, database: master
Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)

ManagedPoolThread #10 17:04:19 ERROR Error installing items/master/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/{FA86AD54-9CEC-4509-9EFD-DD6DBC608A5B}/en/1/xml
Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallItem(BehaviourOptions installOptions, Item targetItem, ItemReference item, XmlVersionParser parser, Boolean& removeVersions)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.GetVersionInstallMode(PackageEntry entry, ItemReference reference, XmlVersionParser parser, ItemInstallerContext context, Boolean& removeVersions)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry)

Comment: Would be helpful if you would attach everything that's in the log files (whole exception details).

Comment: @DawidRutkowski I'm not sure which part to add exactly, but i edited the question and have included the exceptions including "item:saved"

Comment: @DawidRutkowski I reinstalled PS Extensions then tried to reinstall the SXA 1.7 package and it worked.. thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspected i had some corrupted file from the initial powershell extensions installation, so I reinstalled the "Sitecore PowerShell Extensions-4.7.2" package first, then reinstalled the "Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.7" package, and it worked.